# Search for nearest value in an array of doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, search, stl

I have a sorted array of double values in C++.  Is there an STL function that will return the **index** of the **nearest** value in the array to a given double value?

For example, given the following array

```
double myarray[5] = { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4. 1.5, 1.9 };
```

the function call

```
search(myarray, 1.6);
```

should return `3`, the index of the element nearest to 1.6, instead of `-1` (or some other flag value) indicating that the value 1.6 wasn't found.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469477/find-nearest-points-in-a-vector).

Comment: We can use "std::min_element" with a functor, look at my example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

maybe `std::lower_bound` `std::upper_bound` will help you.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a generic solution using `std::lower_bound`:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator, typename T>
BidirectionalIterator getClosest(BidirectionalIterator first, 
                                 BidirectionalIterator last, 
                                 const T & value)
{
    BidirectionalIterator before = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);

    if (before == first) return first;
    if (before == last)  return --last; // iterator must be bidirectional

    BidirectionalIterator after = before;
    --before;

    return (*after - value) < (value - *before) ? after : before;
}
```

You'll notice that I used Bidirectional Iterators, meaning that the function can only work with iterators that can be both incremented and decremented. A better implementation would only impose the Input Iterators concept, but for this problem this should be good enough.

Since you want the index and not an iterator, you can write a little helper function:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator, typename T>
std::size_t getClosestIndex(BidirectionalIterator first, 
                            BidirectionalIterator last, 
                            const T & value)
{
    return std::distance(first, getClosest(first, last, value));
}
```

And now you end up with a code like this:

```
const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 5;
double myarray[ARRAY_LENGTH] = { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4. 1.5, 1.9 };

int getPositionOfLevel(double level)
{
    return getClosestIndex(myarray, myarray + ARRAY_LENGTH, level);
}
```

which gives the following results:

```
level | index
 0.1  |  0
 1.4  |  2
 1.6  |  3
 1.8  |  4
 2.0  |  4
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't use your code, but it helped me find a bug in my own.

Answer (score 3):

Is the array guaranteed to be in ascending order?  If so, give `std::lower_bound`  a look.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed to be in ascending order.  std::lower_bound did work, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think my example do exactly what you want :

(I use std::min_element and a functor)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 5;
double myarray[ARRAY_LENGTH] = { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.9 };

struct CompareDistanceFromLevel
{
    CompareDistanceFromLevel(double cLevel) : level(cLevel) {}

    bool operator()(double lhs, double rhs)
    {
        return std::abs(level - lhs) < std::abs(level - rhs);
    }

private:
    double level;
};

size_t getPositionOfLevel(double level)
{
    double *result;
    result = std::min_element(myarray, myarray+ARRAY_LENGTH, CompareDistanceFromLevel(level));
    return (result-myarray); // returns the index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

static const int array_len = 5;
double myarray[array_len] = { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.9 };

int approx_search(const double val)
{
    double min_val = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<array_len;++i)
    {
        double diff = abs(myarray[i] - val);
        if(diff<min_val)
        {
            min_val = diff;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("approximate %d\n",approx_search(1.6));
    printf("approximate %d\n",approx_search(1.7996));
    printf("approximate %d\n",approx_search(1.4996));
    printf("approximate %d\n",approx_search(0.0002));

    return 0;
 }
```